# How to programmatically check CSS styles for particular elements?

Tags: javascript, css, inline-styles

I can easily check what CSS style an element has if it was applied inline:

```
<p style="color: red;">This is red</p>
```

The JS to read that color:

```
document.querySelector('p').style.color == 'red'
```

How can I check the CSS style of an element if that style was applied from an internal or external stylesheet?

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Trying to do this is normally a code smell. It indicates that you may be trying to use CSS styles as a way to maintain program state, which is generally not a good idea. Judicious use of classes and adding them and removing them can usually make trying to query the current style unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). The returned value is a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), and you can access the properties directly using the dot notation or use `.getPropertyValue('property name')`.

```js
var p = document.querySelector('.demo');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(p);

console.log(style);

console.log('style.color ', style.color);

// or

console.log('getPropertyValue(\'color\')', style.getPropertyValue('color'));
```

```css
.demo {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">This is red</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery css method to get the value of property for the first matched element.  The following code will get the color property for the first p-tag in the document.  Use an id on the element to select a specific tag.

```
var color = $("p").css("color");
```

Comment: We don't use jQuery any more.